# Creating geotiff in arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff

I've added a shapefile and a raster image to ArcGIS, the raster image in geotiff format spreading over some of the features.

Now, I want to create a buffer (of radius 1 mile) around the features and clip them and convert it as a Geotiff image to use it as a raster image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Buffer tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000019000000) to add buffers to create a new shapefile representing the 1 mile buffers.

Then you can use the [Extract by Mask](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002n000000) tool to clip the raster inside of the buffer shapefile features.  Mind you need a Spatial Analyst extension to use this tool.

I recommend using Python or even ModelBuilder to create a loop that will step through each feature in your buffer shapefile, and clip your raster, resulting in individual rasters for each feature that was buffered.  I post another link, but I do not have a high enough reputation.  Simply Google "ArcGIS 10.1 ModelBuilder Iterators".